# Flexigrid - get search options dynamically with jquery

Tags: jquery, search, flexigrid

I am currently using flexigrid and able to find all selected rows using query using:

```
find("tr.trSelected")
```

I am now trying to get the current search options using similar methods but not able to get anything, I have already tried the below but there is no value:

```
find("input[name=q]").val()
```

I would appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not find a solution for the problem the way I was hoping for, I went around the problem using a different approach.

- Add an extra column with name search and hide: true option
- When sending the XML results on search, also send the extra column with

```html
$xml .= "<cell><![CDATA[".$qtype.'='.$query."]]></cell>";
```

- Select the search data from the grid:

```html
$('[abbr="search"]',$(grid).find("tr:first")).text()
```

So now I get my query string as well as the designated column.